# Getting error at prepareStatement

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I'm trying to update entries into a table but i keep getting this error::

> java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Stopped parse at Dec(id104)

MS Access Table Design:

[image]

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Leave_Table SET Jan=?,Feb=?,Mar=?,Apr=?,May=?,Jun=?,Jul=?,Aug=?,Sep=?,Oct=?,Nov=?,Dec=? WHERE LeaveType=?");

            ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(JanuaryTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(FebruaryTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(MarchTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(AprilTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(MayTF.getText()));
        ps.setInt(6,Integer.parseInt(JuneTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(7,Integer.parseInt(JulyTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(8,Integer.parseInt(AugustTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(9,Integer.parseInt(SeptemberTF.getText()));
    ps.setInt(10,Integer.parseInt(OctoberTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(11,Integer.parseInt(NovemberTF.getText()));
            ps.setInt(12,Integer.parseInt(DecemberTF.getText()));
    ps.setString(13,String.valueOf(leavetype.getSelectedItem()));

ps.execute();
```

according to stack trace error seems to be at prepareStatement but i don't seem to get it.

stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Stopped parse at Dec(id104)
    at com.hxtt.global.SQLState.SQLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.a.b.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.bx.o(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.bx.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.d1.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.bx.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.bx.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.bx.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.hxtt.sql.bx.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at leave.LeaveSetting.actionPerformed(LeaveSetting.java:231)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

**Update: the query is running fine with jdbc-odbc bridge but not with hxtt pure java driver 4.0 for MS Access.**

Comment: thanks guys. i did that but now the error is: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error:  Stopped parse at Dec(id104)

Comment: @CyverGypsy See my ans and update your query parameters..

Comment: Can u show your table i mean your bean

Comment: @Krishna not familiar with bean and not using it.

Comment: I am talking about pojo class

Answer (score 1):

**Always use some logical and meaningful column names. Don't make it too short that you can't differentiate it.**

Put spaces before `SET`, `WHERE` and each comma. Try to put all in single string.

```
"UPDATE Leave_Table SET J=?, F=?, M=?, A=?, M=?, J=?, Ju=?, Au=?, Se=?, O=?, N=?, D=? WHERE LeaveType=?"
```

---

--EDIT--

> the error is: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Stopped parse at Dec(id104)

There is no column name `D`. Try with `Dec` instead of `D`

```
"UPDATE Leave_Table SET J=?, F=?, M=?, A=?, M=?, J=?, Ju=?, Au=?, Se=?, O=?, N=?, Dec=? WHERE LeaveType=?"
```

Comment: yes few seconds back,I am deleteing my answer otherwise it will look like I am copying yours,+1

Comment: this is the error now: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Stopped parse at Dec(id104)

Comment: @CyberGypsy print out the sql and check the column names and table name again.

Comment: What is `Dec` here. Is it column name?

Comment: @Braj the statement is working with jdbc odbc bridge but not with HXTT Access Pure Java JDBC 4.0 driver for MS Access  and yeah i slighty modified columns here is the new sql statement "UPDATE Leave_Table SET Jan=?,Feb=?,Mar=?,Apr=?,May=?,Jun=?,Jul=?,Aug=?,Sep=?,Oct=?,Nov=?,Dec=? WHERE LeaveType=?"

Comment: @CyberGypsy Put spaces after each comma.

Comment: @Braj adding spaces after comma doesn't solves this.

Comment: @CyberGypsy Is MS Access accepts case-sensitive queries?

Comment: @Braj it doesn't have to be case sensitive.

Comment: @CyberGypsy try with `ps.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @CyberGypsy Look at the error `java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Stopped parse at Dec(id104)` what is `Dec` here? You haven't answered what I have already asked

Comment: @Braj actually earlier it was exceuteUpdate but while i was experimenting i changed it to execute and Dec is column name check query in above comment.

Comment: @CyberGypsy what is `Dec` here? are you using `Dec` anywhere in your query.

Comment: @Braj Dec is column name

Comment: @CyberGypsy but you used `D` in your query. Why?

Comment: @Braj changed it later while experimenting to see if that was a problem

Comment: @Braj this is my new query:: "UPDATE Leave_Table SET Jan=?,Feb=?,Mar=?,Apr=?,May=?,Jun=?,Jul=?,Aug=?,Sep=?,Oct=?,Nov=?,Dec=? WHERE LeaveType=?"

Comment: @CyberGypsy Oh no its completed changed. What are you doing? just match from the table column names. Its's very simple for you. I don't know what is the structure of the table.

Comment: @CyberGypsy do you want to update just single column based on `LeaveType` got from `String.valueOf(leavetype.getSelectedItem()`? please confirm.

Comment: @Braj no all the columns. as i said the query is correct and running fine with jdbc-odbc bridge but not with hxtt pure java driver.

Comment: @CyberGypsy look at this [sample code](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/420486/cannot-update-database-using-preparedstatement)

Comment: @Braj the above sample will execute but the thing is it uses jdbc-odbc bridge and not hxtt pure java driver which i want to use. my query will also run fine if i use jdbc-odbc bridge.

Comment: @CyberGypsy no idea about `hxtt pure java driver`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to put space do as follows,

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Leave_Table" +
                    " SET J=?,F=?,M=?,A=?,M=?,J=?,Ju=?,Au=?,Se=?,O=?,N=?,D=?" +
                    " WHERE LeaveType=?");
```